# How to get data from firebase array?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to figuring out how to get data from a firebase collection .
Heres my code

```
String myID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    var idofotheruser = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .get();

 idofotheruser.docs.forEach((element) {
      listOfIds.add(element.id);
    });
```

So I get the currentuserid and also every video id. And now I want all documents videos where my id is in the likes array .

Heres how my databse looks

[image]
In the likes array there userids and I want every video where my user id is inside . Every that I liked. If you need more information please leave a comment

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String myID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid;
    var idofotheruser = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('videos')
        .where('likes' arrayContains: myID )
//.get or .snapshot
        .get();

 idofotheruser.docs.forEach((element) {
      listOfIds.add(element.id);
    });
```

mark if it helps

Comment: I need actually get the data not as string instead as Documetnsnapshot

Comment: i dont understand what you are saying... explained better

Comment: First you use a List of String I need List of documementsnapshot. Then u get all likes but I need only get these video where the like array contains my id

Comment: okay i understand what you are saying.... you wan to get document where the the id of the is current user id?

Comment: Check the picture I uploaded . The meinprofilsettings has all ids if every user . For example  Fp3un... and so on has is a user . Also this user liked the video 1037....and so on and I wanna get this video . Well not even this every video that current user like . Current user is String myID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid; Hope this makes it a bit clearer

Comment: i have update the code... note you target the current user by using .doc(myid).where()...... hope you understand....

Comment: You solution was it dont need anymore the where as I said current user is always  only one user so I dont have target him

Comment: Maybe do you know now the answer of the other question ?

Comment: please which other question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67194356/why-im-getting-this-error-class-string-has-no-instance-method-data-receiver?noredirect=1#comment118774407_67194356

Answer (score 0):

```
 //define,=>    data : []   ,<= before onInit().


`async getSubCollections(){
 const idForOtherUser = await this.firestore.collection("videos")
.valueChanges();
 snapshot.subscribe(val=> this.data.push(val));
  console.log(this.data);
  }`
```

In component.html,

```
<div *ngFor ="let value of data">
 {{value}}
</div>
```

---

Comment: Bro im using flutter what you telling me there ???????